# When will it be done? Auf Deutsch

Tags: translation

this is my first post, and I'm looking forward to hearing your advice and insights!

So my question is how would I ask "When will it be done" in the context of perhaps something being cooked or a task that is nearing completion?

My go at it is "Wann wird es getan sein?" Would this make sense to a German speaker or is there a better translation or word for "done"?

Comment: Translation of individual texts is typically considered off-topic here.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Is there a tag category that deals with individual text translations?

Comment: No, off-topic means you are not supposed to ask and the question may be closed fast. Hint: Try [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/When%20will%20it%20be%20done%3F) and possibly other translators and start here if you can't undertsand the results.

Comment: Such questions can be on topic for single word requests and when you do some research, i.e., your question is not so much about the actual translation but the reasoning / background / idioms about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `When will it be done?` use in context of a task

> Wann wird es fertig sein?

or in context of a event use

> Wann ist es soweit?

Comment: When would getan be correct? Dosen't it mean "done" as well? Also, "soweit", in a dictionary translates as 'insofar' or 'on the whole'. How would this make sense in the context of an event use? Is it simply colloquial?

Comment: @SoungPaek Using "getan" gives the sentence another meaning. "Wann wird es getan sein?" is normally not used, but "Es ist getan." for "It is done." is used to show that a really big, exhausting task is finally over, e.g. a murder, summoning the evil overlord,... Oftentimes, the sentence "Es ist getan." is followed by the speaker fainting from exhaustion; so in short: not to be used in everyday language. :)

Comment: Another commonly used word for "done" in the context of some task is "erledigt": "Wann ist die Arbeit erledigt?"